# Split cells themselves (not the data in them) into several columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose I have numbers from 1 to 1000 in column A. How do I split this column into 10 different columns ?
Column A would be 1 to 100, column B would be 101 to 200; etc.
Thanks in advance and sorry about my rusty english, not my native language.

Comment: `=MAKEARRAY(100,10,LAMBDA(r,c,r+(c-1)*100))`

Comment: `=TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(10,100))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that what you actually want to do is take everything in A1:A1000 and break it into 10 columns, you can do it with an INDEX and multiplexed indexation to reshape it, but, as a lazy alternative, here is a general purpose reshaper that I made. It has a lot of overhead as a protection for error handling as well as some hooks for re-ordering, but it will do what you want.

With Office 365:

```
=LET( Matrix, A1:A1000,
      newRows, ,
      newCols, 10,

       rdR, ROWS( Matrix ),
       rdC, COLUMNS( Matrix ),
       rdCells, rdR * rdC,
       rdIR, SEQUENCE( 1, rdCells, 0 ),
       wrR, IF( newRows > 0, newRows,
                      IF( newCols > 0, ROUNDUP( rdCells/newCols, 0), rdR ) ),
       wrC, IF( newCols = 0, ROUNDUP( rdCells/wrR, 0), newCols ),
       wrCells, wrR * wrC,
       wrIR, SEQUENCE( wrR, wrC, 0 ),
       mux, INDEX( Matrix, rdIR/rdC + 1, MOD( rdIR, rdC ) + 1 ),
       demux, INDEX( mux, wrIR/wrCells +  1, wrIR + MOD( wrIR, wrC)*(wrR - 1) - INT( wrIR/wrC ) * (wrC - 1) ),
       demux
     )
```

***I put in the wrong write order - fixed now***

> ***12 Feb : I found one more error and it is fixed now***

You can enter whatever number of rows you want in **newRows** and whatever number of columns you want in **newCols**. If you leave either blank, it calculates the other.

Comment: Thx mark, that was really helpful.

Comment: Hi @JorgeDias - I just saw that there was yet another error. Honestly, I pulled up an old XLS, copied the formula and simplified it for your case. Only later did I realize (twice) that the simplification had a flaw in it. The previous version drifts because of the error. This version is correct (and tested and tested and tested).